# How should I interpret this に?

Tags: translation, particle-に

> お前の姿**に**瓜二つだからこそ、むしろ許せない…！

Is it something that goes along with だからこそ and therefore means "because"? I know that this is one of the meanings of に but I'm not sure if this is the one used in this case since だから already expresses the idea of "because.."

Answer (score 2):

Coming after 姿, the に functions as the same way as it does in ～にみえる and ～に近い. Basically 'in relation to ______' or colloquially 'as'.

だからこそ does indeed function as 'because' or 'especially because'.

瓜二つ is like saying 'Two peas in a pod'. I.e., having the same appearance or form as another.

そのおばは私の母に瓜二つだ - That lady is the spitting image of my mother.

そのおばは私の母にそっくりだ - [Same meaning as above]

Broken apart: お前の姿(Your appearance) に (as) 瓜二つ (strikingly similar) だからこそ (For that reason/that's why) むしろ (rather)　許せない (not forgive).

Rather literal translation: [He/She/It] has identical appearance to you. That's why I'd rather not forgive [you]!

Attempted figurative translation: I really can't let it go because he looks just like you!

If anyone else wants to tackle this one, the original text can be found [here](http://jbcs.info/Umineko/ep6-jp.html).

Comment: Is に always used with words like 似合う, そっくり.. ?

Comment: While it is much less practiced in modern Japanese, と is sometimes used instead. Whether に or と, however, an indirect object marker (?) should be used.